# How do I use the render function correctly in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm just starting to use the render function and came across
with one problem.
When rendering, the Home component does not display app routes
registered in

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Vue Router Demo App</h1>

    <p>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'hello' }">Hello World</router-link>
    </p>

    <div class="container">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {}
</script>
```

there are no errors in the browser console.

**app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import App from './App'
import Hello from './views/Hello'
import Home from './views/Home'




const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/hello',
      name: 'hello',
      component: Hello,
    },
  ],
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  router,
});
```

**Home.vue**

with this configuration, the routes are not displayed

```
<script>
export default {}
import Vue from 'vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement("div", { class: "container" }, [
      createElement("p", { class: "my-class" }, "Some cool text")
    ])
  }

});
</script>
```

I just want to use the render function inside my components. Or understand how to use the render function correctly for two or more vue components.

How to configure the app correctly with switching between components
`Home` and `Hello`?

Answer (score 0):

The components in Vue should be inherited from vue components and injected in the base component.

```js
Vue.component('home', {
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement("div", { class: "container" }, [
      createElement("p", { class: "my-class" }, "Some cool text")
    ])
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: ['home'],
  template: '<home/>'
})
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
```